# Google Guice can't work with two modules

Tags: java, guice

I create injector:

```
private static Injector mvpInjector = Guice.createInjector(
    HandlingModule.getInstance(),
    StorageModule.getInstance()
);
```

Then I try to get instance of class:

```
mvpInjector.getInstance(ImageCreatePresenter.class).showImageCreateWindow();
```

This is class' constructor, that need to inject:

```
@Inject
public ImageCreatePresenterImpl(ImageCreateView imageCreateView, StorageHelper storageHelper, ImageCreater imageCreater) {
    this.imageCreateView = imageCreateView;
    this.storageHelper = storageHelper;
    this.imageCreater = imageCreater;
}
```

But, during the inject, throw exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.dugin.rostislav.StorageHelper was bound.
  while locating com.dugin.rostislav.StorageHelper
    for parameter 1 at com.dugin.rostislav.presenter.ImageCreatePresenterImpl.<init>(ImageCreatePresenterImpl.java:26)
  at com.dugin.rostislav.modules.HandlingModule.configure(HandlingModule.java:32)
```

---

My modules:

1.

```
public class HandlingModule extends AbstractModule {
    private static final HandlingModule module = new HandlingModule();

    private HandlingModule() {
        //Closed constructor
    }

    public static HandlingModule getInstance() {
        return module;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MainWindowPresenter.class).to(MainWindowPresenterImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ImageCreatePresenter.class).to(ImageCreatePresenterImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

        bind(ImageCreater.class).to(ImageCreaterImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

        bind(ImageCreateView.class).to(ImageCreateViewImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MainView.class).to(MainViewImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

2.

```
public final class StorageModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final static StorageModule module = new StorageModule();

    private TypeListener storageHelperListener = new TypeListener() {
        @Override
        public <I> void hear(final TypeLiteral<I> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<I> typeEncounter) {
            typeEncounter.register(new InjectionListener<I>() {
                @Override
                public void afterInjection(Object o) {
                    if (o instanceof StorageHelper) {
                        try {
                            ((StorageHelper) o).initDB();
                        } catch (DBInitializationException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private StorageModule() {
        //Closed constructor
    }

    public static StorageModule getInstance() {
        return module;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ImageDB.class).to(SQLiteDB.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(StorageHelper.class).to(StorageHelperImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ImagesHelper.class).to(ImagesHelperImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

        bind(String.class)
                .annotatedWith(Names.named(StorageModuleConst.DB_FOLDER_PATH))
                .toProvider(Providers.of(StorageConst.OSLOADER_DATA_FOLDER));
        bind(String.class)
                .annotatedWith(Names.named(StorageModuleConst.IMAGES_FOLDER_PATH))
                .toProvider(Providers.of(StorageConst.OSLOADER_IMAGES_FOLDER));

        bindListener(Matchers.any(), storageHelperListener);
    }
}
```

Not my class exist!

---

Why I take error and how it fix?

---

*StorageHelperImpl* constructor:

```
    @Inject
    public StorageHelperImpl(@NonNull ImageDB database, @NonNull ImagesHelper imagesHelper) {
        this.database = database;
        this.imagesHelper = imagesHelper;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the constructor of (or the way you inject) `StorageHelperImpl`.

Comment: Also, is it possible that it's a package issue? For instance, you create two classes with the same name in two different packages? I think here about `StorageModule` and `StorageHelper`. Check all your imports.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, no... I have only one class with each name. I update question.

Comment: You are calling initDb on your listener that can throw an exception, Is there a chance your initDb is throwing an exception and therefore will never be bound to your StorageHelper?

Comment: @pandaadb, no. In stacktrace about exception daesn't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
Guice.createInjector(Modules.combine(HandlingModule.getInstance(),  StorageModule.getInstance()));
```

Comment: @hunter Can you explain what makes `Modules.combine(...)` work in this case? I'm just flabbergasted and I don't understand! (Also happy it helped bukashka101.)